# Как в Jupyter Notebook отображать графики параллельно с выполнением кода c помощью pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
for i in range(10):
    y.append(i ** 2)
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Нужно, чтобы такой код каждую секунду обновлял старый график (а не рисовал новый), и на второй секунде у меня была прямая, соединяющая (0, 0) и (1, 1), а после десятой секунды - парабола

Comment: https://pythonawesome.com/create-real-time-plots-in-jupyter-notebooks/

Answer (score 0):

Просто замените в вашем коде

> time.sleep(1)

на

> ```
> plt.pause(1)
> ```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, точно так же рисует ещё один новый график

Comment: Ну, если исправлять по одной строчке раз в неделю.... Попробуйте тогда через jupyterplot как посоветовали выше.